# Why is this C++ min and max currency algorithm code not working? Using this code, I want to extract min and max prices from a currency trading

Tags: c++17

Take a look at this code. I want to extract the minimum and maximum ask prices and print these out as part of the statistics:

```cpp
    double OrderBook::getHighPrice(std::vector<OrderBookEntry>& orders)
        {
            // find the highest value in array of value
            double max = orders[0].price;
            for (OrderBookEntry& e : orders)
            {
                if (e.price > max)
                {
                    max = e.price;
                }
                return max;
            }
        }
        double OrderBook::getLowPrice(std::vector<OrderBookEntry>& orders)
        {
            // find the lowest value in array of value
            double min = orders[0].price;
            for (OrderBookEntry& e : orders)
            {
                if (e.price < min)
                {
                    min = e.price;
                }
                return min;
            }
        }
```

Here is an extract of the output I am getting, max and min are the same:

```
    Product: BTC/USDT
     Asks seen: 50
     Max ask: 5352
     Min ask: 5352
     Product: DOGE/BTC
     Asks seen: 50
     Max ask: 3.1e-07
     Min ask: 3.1e-07
     Product: DOGE/USDT
     Asks seen: 50
     Max ask: 0.00165524
     Min ask: 0.00165524
     Product: ETH/BTC
     Asks seen: 50
     Max ask: 0.0218909
     Min ask: 0.0218909
     Product: ETH/USDT
     Asks seen: 50
     Max ask: 117.329
     Min ask: 117.329
    1: Print help
    2: Print exchange stats
    3: Make an offer
    4: Make a bid
    5: Print wallet
    6: Continue
    ==============
    Current time is: 2020/03/17 17:01:24.884492
    Type in 1-6
```

I want to make sure that max and min are different and correct. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning from inside the `for` loops. You need to wait until all the prices have been checked and then return after the `for` loops:

```
    double OrderBook::getHighPrice(std::vector<OrderBookEntry>& orders)
    {
        // find the highest value in array of value
        double max = orders[0].price;
        for (OrderBookEntry& e : orders)
        {
            if (e.price > max)
            {
                max = e.price;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    
    double OrderBook::getLowPrice(std::vector<OrderBookEntry>& orders)
    {
        // find the lowest value in array of value
        double min = orders[0].price;
        for (OrderBookEntry& e : orders)
        {
            if (e.price < min)
            {
                min = e.price;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

Comment: What a stupid oversight. I was looking in the wrong places. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CAGTECH Not related to your question, but you really do not want to be using floating-point types for prices.  Most systems dealing with prices shift every price by a constant power of 10 and use integers for everything.